# how to enter a directory as a command line argument

Tags: bash, command-line

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter a Directory Name:
read

if [ -d "$1" ];
 then
  find "$1" -type f -size 0 -delete
  find "$1" *.tmp -type f -delete
  find "$1" *.swp -type f -delete
  tar -cvzf mytarfile.tgz "$1"
else
  echo "This is not a directory"
fi
```

The script runs when I put in the directory myself using              ./program.sh Desktop. If I have an empty txt, .tmp and .swp file on my desktop it removes them and makes a tar file. How can I enter a directory at the (read) line for example Documents or MyMusic. It allows me to type in something but then goes right to the else and prints "This is not a directory.

Comment: The second and third `find` commands do not do what you seem to want; they delete all files (of any type) in the specified directory, and also the .tmp and .swp files in the current directory (*not* the specified one). I'm pretty sure you want e.g. `find "$1" -name '*.swp' -type f -delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to read the Directory name,like:

```
echo "Enter a Directory Name:"
read Dir_Name
```

or better:

```
read -p "Enter Directory Name:" Dir_Name
```

and then replace all `$1` with `${Dir_Name}`

`$1` is a special variable in Unix.
Read it here: [special variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm)

Comment: `${Dir_Name}` could be safely replaced with $Dir_Name.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all `$1` with `$REPLY`.

---

Take a look at read's syntax: `help read`

Comment: Ok I will. Thank you.